# firebug console error : invalid label

Tags: jquery

following is my jQuery function, please correct if possible and let me know where am i mistaking.

```
   $("#id").click(function() {
        start : appendLayout(this.id)  // invoking another function to do and this part is working.
        stop : (function(){
                   if(true){ alert("please create project"); }
                 } )   // not working, getting error in firbug console if i change anything

   });
```

Comment: What is start and stop? What you have shown here is invalid javascript.

Comment: i was trying to perform the task in two events that is why i used `start  stop`

Comment: what events? There are no such events start and stop. You have the click event.

Comment: ohh i see. sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do? You're creating some properties in a function, which is not an object.

This is wrong:

```
function() {
        firstName: 'Saeed',
        lastName: 'Neamati'
   });
```

This is the right way of creating objects:

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'Saeed',
    lastName: 'Neamati'
}
```

Simply call functions and write simple JavaScript statements inside your function:

```
$("#id").click(function() {
        appendLayout(this.id);
        if(true){ alert("please create project"); }
});
```